# Identify a pouch lithium battery by its regulator board

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, identification

I’m wanting to replace a small lithium pouch battery that is unlabeled and not holding a charge (for well under a minute) and is swelling. It is about 10x20mm and looks like it may have been 2-3mm thick. While that could hardly be enough to go on, I got some good pictures of the regulator board it’s attached to.

If it’s helpful I’ll describe the components on the 4x8mm board: there are 2 6-pin surface mount DIP chips labeled “DW01B” and “8205A” each next to a surface mount resistor labeled “101” and “102” respectively. Between these there is an unlabeled surface mount capacitor. On the back of the board I can make out “1320” silk-screened on it.

Thanks in advance:

[UPDATED:] In the photograph I just noticed “75S” looks partially visible in the glue on the battery pouch. I can see no hint of this text with my naked eye.

[UPDATED 2:] I had originally misread the 8205A as a 205A, not seeing the “8”

[image: front of the “regulator board”]
[image: back of the “regulator board”]
[image: number silk-screened on the back]

Comment: It's not a regulator board, it's a battery pack protection board. It won't help identifying your battery.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, size is just what you need to find a replacement cell.

Take [this example from Amazon:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TXJ5XXZ)

[image]

The dimensions of the cell are 9mmX55mmX80mm.  The protection board adds another 2mm to the length.

The cell is marked "PL 905580" and "3.7V 5000mAh."

The "PL 905580" is nothing more than the dimensions.

Find a cell with the same dimensions as the one you have.  They all have the same voltage rating, and the capacity will be (approximately) the same.

Measure just the cell, then find one with the same dimensions.

---

The number "1320" printed on the circuit board might be related to the size of the cell.  You say the cell is about 10mmX20mm - that's a fair match to the numbers.

Comment: So far this is the closest I’ve found, thanks to your help: 3.7V 70mAh 401220 Lipo Battery https://a.co/d/5x0D2Sa

Comment: Check the dimensions of the complete cell (with the protection PCB,) and measure the existing space in the device.  If it all fits, go for it.